# How to display recorded webinars AND future webinars in search results

Tags: filter, search-results, sort

Similar to this issue but slightly different. [Sort order when I have events and products](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61397/sort-order-when-i-have-events-and-products)

I have a page that shows webinars available for purchase in a card-like format. Users can filter and see upcoming webinars (future date), recorded webinars (past date) and All Webinars (a mix of upcoming and recorded webinars).

We currently default to showing All Webinars sorted by most recent. Most recent sorting is our default and only sorting capability at the moment. We don't want to list past webinars first (their date doesn't matter at this point) and we're burying upcoming webinars down the page that we'd want to prioritize showing.

The linked issue above (from 7 years ago) had comments that recommended listing both types of webinars but in separate buckets on one page. I feel like this is a potential solution, but am not sure how to implement for my scenario of recorded and upcoming webinars?

Our webinars cater to a range of finance professions and offer everything from How to use excel more effectively, how to train your tellers, to overviews of specific government acts that you should know to stay in compliance. Very broad range of content. We also have a roster of 30 or so instructors that create and run webinars for us. I'd also mention that price doesn't change much across events and our customers aren't phased by price typically.

Any tips for a more intuitive experience?

Here is our filter design for reference.

[image: filter design]

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the issue of limitations very well, especially when it's oneself who decides them.

---

The question says:

> it doesn't make sense to sort by most recent first...

> we wouldn't want to list past webinars first ...

> we would be burying upcoming webinars down the page that we'd want to prioritize showing since they're upcoming

Perfect, **don't do any of those three things!**

A filter has two priority functions, one for the user `a` and one for the site owner `b`:

- `a`: help find a product easily
- `b`: facilitate to show/sale the products

As the site owner, which one is your priority?

If the answer is `a` as a user I would be interested in searching webinars by (this order is my preference as a consumer, maybe not the generic one):

1. Price
2. Subject
3. Duration
4. Top sales
5. Upcoming
6. Offers
7. Specifics (author, ...)
8. Other

If the answer is `b` as a seller I would be interested in showing webinars by:

1. Top sales
2. Featured (weekly, monthly, by author...)
3. Most recent
4. Upcoming
5. Offers (buy 3 pay 2,...)
6. Others

---

If I want to see all the webinars, as a user I have no preference, I want to see them all, I can spend an entire afternoon playing with the scroll bar. But, as a seller, I have preferences, I would show an order prioritizing the best placed within a ranking of the `b` list.

---

BTW: this answer is generic, I don't know what webinars are about as it's not mentioned in the question

Comment: Thanks for the response! Great thoughts. For reference, our webinars cater to a range of financial service professions and offer everything from How to use Excel more effectively, how to train your bank tellers, to overviews of specific government acts that you should know to stay in compliance. Very broad range of content. We also have a roster of 30 or so instructors that create and run webinars for us. I'd also mention that price doesn't change much across events.

Comment: You should edit the Q and add all this info. In any case, my answer is about getting your priorities in order and taking the best of them to show the webinars.

Comment: Question edited. Thanks for the feedback.